# Composite expected in C++

Tags: c++, monads

I'm interested in creating a successor to the `expected` monad in C++. Specifically I want it to be capable of storing error which may has one of many types, and a value. I believe this is enough to be able to build execution pipelines with easy error handling.

The limitation of the simple expected is that we have to write code like this:

```cxx
auto res1 = f();
if ( !res1 )
{
    ...
}

auto res2 = g( res1 );
if ( !res2 )
{
    ...
}

auto res3 = t( res2 );
```

This looks like code bloat, especially if all the errors should be processed in a some common way.

I suggest the way to overcome this limitation by allowing expected to store many types of errors (therefore it is composite expected). Then it'd be possible to write pipeline and process errors like this:

```cxx
auto res = f() >> g >> t;
if ( !res )
{
    ...    
}
```

there is also a possibility to invoke functions taking many arguments, with use of `then` member function:

```cxx
auto res = f().then( args_before, g, args_after ).then( t );
```

Link to the [implementation](https://github.com/andrewerf/composite_expected/blob/7c4a037103575602ae12e60058505dc758ec7cc2/include/composite_expected.h#L158).

P.S. Please do not pay too much attention to the implementation details. I'm most interested in the presented concept, not in the specific implementation. However, any notes are very welcomed.

```cxx
#include <concepts>
#include <variant>
#include <functional>
#include <stdexcept>

class make_variant_index_error : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    enum Reason
    {
        BadIndex,
        BadArgs
    };

    explicit make_variant_index_error( Reason reason ):
        std::runtime_error( reason == BadIndex ? "Specified index is greater than number of variant alternatives" : "Specified index is not constructable from specified args" )
    {}
};


namespace details
{

template <typename T>
struct is_variant
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <typename ...Ts>
struct is_variant<std::variant<Ts...>>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_variant_v = is_variant<T>::value;


template <size_t rIndex, typename ...Ts, typename ...Args>
constexpr std::variant<Ts...> make_variant_index_impl_from_args( size_t index, Args&& ...args )
{
    if ( index == rIndex )
    {
        if constexpr ( std::is_constructible_v<std::variant<Ts...>, std::in_place_index_t<rIndex>, Args...> )
            return std::variant<Ts...>( std::in_place_index<rIndex>, std::forward<Args>( args )... );
        else
            throw make_variant_index_error( make_variant_index_error::BadArgs );
    } else if constexpr ( rIndex == sizeof...( Ts ) - 1 )
        throw make_variant_index_error( make_variant_index_error::BadIndex );
    else
        return make_variant_index_impl_from_args<rIndex + 1, Ts...>( index, std::forward<Args>( args )... );
}

template <size_t rIndexNew, size_t rIndexOld, typename ...Ts, typename OtherVariant>
    requires is_variant_v<std::remove_cvref_t<OtherVariant>>
constexpr std::variant<Ts...> make_variant_index_impl_from_other( size_t indexNew, size_t indexOld, OtherVariant&& other )
{
    using OtherVariantNoCvRef = std::remove_cvref_t<OtherVariant>;
    if ( indexNew == rIndexNew )
    {
        if ( indexOld == rIndexOld )
        {
            if constexpr ( std::is_constructible_v<std::variant<Ts...>, std::in_place_index_t<rIndexNew>, std::variant_alternative_t<rIndexOld, OtherVariantNoCvRef>> )
                return std::variant<Ts...>( std::in_place_index<rIndexNew>,
                                            std::get<rIndexOld>( std::forward<OtherVariant>( other ) ) );
            else
                throw make_variant_index_error( make_variant_index_error::BadArgs );
        } else if constexpr ( rIndexOld == std::variant_size_v<OtherVariantNoCvRef> - 1 )
            throw make_variant_index_error( make_variant_index_error::BadIndex );
        else
            return make_variant_index_impl_from_other<rIndexNew, rIndexOld + 1, Ts...>( indexNew, indexOld,
                                                                                        std::forward<OtherVariant>(
                                                                                                other ));
    } else if constexpr ( rIndexNew == sizeof...( Ts ) - 1 )
        throw make_variant_index_error( make_variant_index_error::BadIndex );
    else
        return make_variant_index_impl_from_other<rIndexNew + 1, rIndexOld, Ts...>( indexNew, indexOld,
                                                                                    std::forward<OtherVariant>(
                                                                                            other ));
}

template <typename T>
struct make_variant_index_t;

template <typename ...Ts>
struct make_variant_index_t<std::variant<Ts...>>
{
    template <typename OtherVariant>
        requires is_variant_v<std::remove_cvref_t<OtherVariant>>
    constexpr static std::variant<Ts...> fromOther( size_t indexNew, size_t indexOld, OtherVariant&& other )
    {
        if ( indexNew >= sizeof...( Ts ) || indexOld >= std::variant_size_v<std::remove_cvref_t<OtherVariant>> )
            throw make_variant_index_error( make_variant_index_error::BadIndex );
        else
            return make_variant_index_impl_from_other<0, 0, Ts...>( indexNew, indexOld,
                                                                    std::forward<OtherVariant>( other ));
    }

    template <typename ...Args>
    constexpr static std::variant<Ts...> fromArgs( size_t index, Args&& ...args )
    {
        if ( index >= sizeof...( Ts ))
            throw make_variant_index_error( make_variant_index_error::BadIndex );
        else
            return make_variant_index_impl_from_args<0, Ts...>( index, std::forward<Args>( args )... );
    }
};


template <typename T, typename J>
struct variant_add
{
};

template <typename T, typename J> requires ( !is_variant_v<T> && !is_variant_v<J> )
struct variant_add<T, J>
{
    using type = std::variant<T, J>;
};

template <typename T, typename ...Ts> requires ( !is_variant_v<T> )
struct variant_add<T, std::variant<Ts...>>
{
    using type = std::variant<T, Ts...>;
};

template <typename T, typename ...Ts> requires ( !is_variant_v<T> )
struct variant_add<std::variant<Ts...>, T>
{
    using type = std::variant<Ts..., T>;
};

template <typename ...Ts, typename ...Js>
struct variant_add<std::variant<Ts...>, std::variant<Js...>>
{
    using type = std::variant<Ts..., Js...>;
};


template <typename T>
struct variant_slice_first;

template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct variant_slice_first<std::variant<T, Ts...>>
{
    using type = std::variant<Ts...>;
};

template <typename T>
using variant_slice_first_t = typename variant_slice_first<T>::type;


}


template <typename T, typename ...Errs>
class composite_expected
{
public:
    using variant_t = std::variant<T, Errs...>;
private:
    variant_t variant_;

    template <typename Other>
        requires details::is_variant_v<typename Other::variant_t>
    using united_t =
        typename details::variant_add<
            typename details::variant_add<
                std::variant_alternative_t<0, typename Other::variant_t>,
                details::variant_slice_first_t<variant_t>
            >::type,
            details::variant_slice_first_t<typename Other::variant_t>>::type;

    template <typename Ret, typename Other>
        requires details::is_variant_v<std::remove_cvref_t<Other>>
    static auto united( Other&& other )
    {
        return other.index() == 0
                ? from_variant_t<Ret>( details::make_variant_index_t<Ret>::fromOther( 0, 0, std::forward<Other>( other ) ) )
                : from_variant_t<Ret>(
                        details::make_variant_index_t<Ret>::fromOther( sizeof...( Errs ) + other.index(), other.index(), std::forward<Other>( other ) )
                );
    }

public:

    template <typename J>
    struct from_variant;

    template <typename ...Ts>
    struct from_variant<std::variant<Ts...>>
    {
        using type = composite_expected<Ts...>;
    };

    template <typename ...Ts>
    using from_variant_t = typename from_variant<Ts...>::type;

    using value_type = T;

    template <typename ...Args>
    static composite_expected<T, Errs...> fromErr( size_t errIndex, Args&& ...args )
    {
        return composite_expected( details::make_variant_index_t<decltype( variant_ )>::fromArgs( errIndex + 1, std::forward<Args>( args )... ) );
    }

    template <typename ...Args>
    static composite_expected<T, Errs...> fromVal( Args&& ...args )
    {
        return composite_expected( std::in_place_index<0>, std::forward<Args>( args )... );
    }

    template <typename ...Args>
    explicit composite_expected( Args&& ...args ):
        variant_( std::forward<Args>( args )... )
    {}

    template <typename TFwd>
        requires std::convertible_to<std::remove_cvref_t<TFwd>, T>
    composite_expected( TFwd&& val ):
        variant_( std::in_place_index<0>, std::forward<TFwd>( val ) )
    {}

    [[nodiscard]] const variant_t& variant() const
    {
        return variant_;
    }

    variant_t&& variant()
    {
        return std::move( variant_ );
    }

    explicit operator bool() const
    {
        return variant_.index() == 0;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] const T& value() const
    {
        return std::get<0>( variant_ );
    }

    T&& value()
    {
        return std::get<0>( std::move( variant_ ) );
    }

    [[nodiscard]] std::variant<Errs...> error() const
    {
        return details::make_variant_index_t<std::variant<Errs...>>::fromOther( variant_.index() - 1, variant_.index(), variant_ );
    }

    std::variant<Errs...> error()
    {
        return details::make_variant_index_t<std::variant<Errs...>>::fromOther( variant_.index() - 1, variant_.index(), std::move( variant_ ) );
    }

    [[nodiscard]] size_t errorIndex() const
    {
        return variant_.index() - 1;
    }

    template <typename ...Args1, typename Functor, typename ...Args2>
        requires details::is_variant_v<typename std::invoke_result_t<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>::variant_t>
    auto then( Args1&& ...args1, Functor f, Args2&& ...args2 )
    {
        using Ret = united_t<std::invoke_result_t<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>>;
        return *this ? united<Ret>( std::invoke( f, std::forward<Args1>( args1 )..., std::move( value() ), std::forward<Args2>( args2 )... ).variant() )
                     : from_variant_t<Ret>( details::make_variant_index_t<Ret>::fromOther( variant_.index(), variant_.index(), std::move( variant_ ) ) );
    }

    template <typename ...Args1, typename Functor, typename ...Args2>
        requires details::is_variant_v<typename std::invoke_result_t<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>::variant_t>
    auto then( Args1&& ...args1, Functor f, Args2&& ...args2 ) const
    {
        using Ret = united_t<std::invoke_result_t<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>>;
        return *this ? united<Ret>( std::invoke( f, std::forward<Args1>( args1 )..., value(), std::forward<Args2>( args2 )... ).variant() )
                     : from_variant_t<Ret>( details::make_variant_index_t<Ret>::fromOther( variant_.index(), variant_.index(), variant_ ) );
    }

    template <typename ...Args1, typename Functor, typename ...Args2>
        requires ( std::invocable<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>
            && !requires { typename std::invoke_result_t<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>::variant_t; } )
    auto then( Args1&& ...args1, Functor f, Args2&& ...args2 )
    {
        using Ret = std::variant<std::invoke_result_t<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>, Errs...>;
        return *this ? from_variant_t<Ret>::fromVal( std::invoke( f, std::forward<Args1>( args1 )..., std::move( value() ), std::forward<Args1>( args2 )... ) )
                     : from_variant_t<Ret>( details::make_variant_index_t<Ret>::fromOther( variant_.index(), variant_.index(), std::move( variant_ ) ) );
    }

    template <typename ...Args1, typename Functor, typename ...Args2>
        requires ( std::invocable<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>
            && !requires { typename std::invoke_result_t<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>::variant_t; } )
   auto then( Args1&& ...args1, Functor f, Args2&& ...args2 ) const
    {
        using Ret = std::variant<std::invoke_result_t<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>, Errs...>;
        return *this ? from_variant_t<Ret>::fromVal( std::invoke( f, std::forward<Args1>( args1 )..., value(), std::forward<Args2>( args2 )... ) )
                     : from_variant_t<Ret>( details::make_variant_index_t<Ret>::fromOther( variant_.index(), variant_.index(), variant_ ) );
    }


    template <std::invocable<T> Functor>
    auto operator >>( Functor f )
    {
        return then( f );
    }

    template <std::invocable<T> Functor>
    auto operator >>( Functor f ) const
    {
        return then( f );
    }
};
```

And some use cases from tests.

```cxx
template <typename T>
composite_expected<T, const char*> sqrt( T x )
{
    if ( x >= 0 )
        // implicit constructor from value
        return std::sqrt( x );
    else
        return composite_expected<T, const char*>::fromErr( 0, "Could not take sqr-root of negative number" );
}


TEST( composite_expected, logic )
{
    const auto x = composite_expected<int, int>::fromVal( 100 );
    ASSERT_TRUE( x );
    ASSERT_EQ( x.value(), 100 );

    // calling with multiple arguments
    const auto y = x.then( std::multiplies(), -2 );
    static_assert( std::same_as<decltype( y ), const composite_expected<int, int>> );
    ASSERT_TRUE( y );
    ASSERT_EQ( y.value(), -200 );

    auto z = x >> sqrt<int>;
    static_assert( std::same_as<decltype( z ), composite_expected<int, int, const char*>> );
    ASSERT_TRUE( z );
    ASSERT_EQ( z.value(), 10 );

    z = y >> sqrt<int>;
    ASSERT_FALSE( z );
    ASSERT_EQ( z.errorIndex(), 1 );
    ASSERT_EQ( strcmp( std::get<1>( z.error() ), "Could not take sqr-root of negative number" ), 0 );
}
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty straightforward review request of actual code, not a hypothetical design. That the OP is more interested in a review that focuses on the public interface rather than the internal guts shouldn’t be disqualifying.

Comment: What the request is lacking, though, is all of the code. There seems to be some stuff in there that is undefined. Some seems obvious enough to guess what it’s doing, like `is_variant`. Others are completely opaque, like `variant_add`. If there isn’t enough code in there to make it compile-able, *that* should be disqualifying.

Comment: @indi edited so that question contains _all_ the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Design review

I’m skeptical of the idea that anyone would ever need a type that returns a value or one of *multiple* error types. That seems a bit excessive. I mean, imagine a square root function that returns a value if successful… or a `std::error_code` on failure, or a `std::string` describing the problem, or a `std::complex` with the result if a complex result is possible, or a `std::vector` with a bunch of a suggested alternative arguments that wouldn’t fail… or… or… or….

I mean, okay, there are situations where `std::expected` may be insufficient. The best example illustrating that, in my opinion, is Niall Douglas’s `outcome`. ([Here’s a link to the Boost version](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/outcome/doc/html/tutorial/essential/outcome.html).) Ignoring the policy argument, `outcome` has two error types, but those error types mean two very different things: the first one is for *recoverable* errors, while the second is for *unrecoverable* errors. Very basically, an error of the first type means “I couldn’t do what you wanted with the arguments you gave… but you could change your request in some way and try again, and it will work”, while the second means “nothing you could have done would have prevented this error, and it’s likely nothing you can do will prevent it happening again, so there’s no point retrying”. An example of where the difference might matter might be when you are loading configuration data: if the configuration simply isn’t there, that’s a problem, but one that you can solve by either using defaults, or pausing to query the user for what they want… but if you tried to read the configuration and the file was corrupt, or the disk had a read error, well that’s also a problem, but one that should never, ever happen in normal operation, and there’s nothing you can do (in the program) to fix it.

So I’m on board with an extended `expected`. Just… not quite as extended as you’re imagining.

I would say that all anyone would ever need is `outcome`. I think that covers literally any possibility that anyone could ever want. You have your value, you have a space for errors that that calling code can potentially recover from, and you have a space for *anything else* that could ever happen but never should (unless something is really, really wrong). Using the square root example, you have your return value, you have a space for “there is no (real) result for the argument you gave (but you could give me a different argument, or you could use complex numbers)”, and you have a space for “the math co-processor is literally on fire”. And of course, `expected` (or `result`, to use Douglas’s terminology) is the simpler case where there isn’t a reason to distinguish between types of errors.

Okay, but what if you really *do* want multiple error types? What if you really *do* want to return a `error_code`, a `string`, or a `complex` from `sqrt()`? Well, for that strange and rare case, you just need `expected<double, variant<error_code, string, complex<double>>`. In other words, you don’t need `expected<ValueType, ErrorTypes...>`. You just need the standard `expected<ValueType, ErrorType>`, and you can use a `variant<ErrorTypes...>`. (Or, of course, something like `outcome<ValueType, RecoverableErrorType, UnrecoverableErrorType>`, where the latter two types could be variants.)

Or, even better, a custom type to hold multiple error types. So `sqrt()` could return a `expected<double, sqrt_error_t>`, where `sqrt_error_t` is a struct holds a `complex<double>` and an `error_code`, and throws an exception by default, so you could use it like this:

```
auto better_sqrt(double) -> std::expected<double, sqrt_error_t>;

// Simple use
auto res = better_sqrt(arg).value();    // throws on error

// Advanced use (not all of this is required, of course; use as much of it as
// you need for a given use case)
try
{
    if (auto res = better_sqrt(arg); res.has_value())
    {
        auto val = res.value(); // this is a double
        // do real calculations...
    }
    else
    {
        auto val = res.error().complex_value(); // either a complex<double>,
                                                // or throws if even that could
                                                // not be calculated
        // do complex calculations...
    }
}
// sqrt_error_t inherits from std::exception, so this works:
catch (std::exception const& x)
{
    // Could not calculate a real *OR* complex square root, so report error.
}

// Alternate form, to avoid non-deterministic exception costs
if (auto res = better_sqrt(arg); res.has_value())
{
    auto val = res.value(); // this is a double
    // do real calculations...
}
else if (res.has_complex_value())
{
    auto val = res.error().complex_value(); // this is a complex<double>
    // do complex calculations...
}
else
{
    // Could not calculate a real *OR* complex square root, so report error.
}
```

How would that compare to the `composite_expected` interface?

```
auto better_sqrt(double) -> std::composite_expected<double, std::complex<double>, std::error_code>;

// Simple use
auto res = better_sqrt(arg).value();    // throws on error

// Advanced use
try
{
    if (auto res = better_sqrt(arg); res)
    {
        auto val = res.value(); // this is a double
                                // WARNING: This is the one and only time you
                                // can call res.value(). If you accidentally
                                // call it a second time... UB.
        // do real calculations...
    }
    else if (res.errorIndex() == 1)
    // WARNING: Do not do:
    //  if (std::holds_alternative<complex<double>>(res.error()))
    // because you can only call `res.error()` once, and if you do it here,
    // you can’t do it below.
    {
        // WARNING: error index is 1, but we have to use index 0.
        auto val = std::get<0>(res.error());    // this is a complex<double>
                                                // or:
                                                //  auto val = std::get<std::complex<double>>(res.error());
        // do complex calculations...
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::system_error{std::get<1>(res.error())};
        // or:
        //  throw std::system_error{std::get<std::error_code>(res.error())};
    }
}
catch (std::exception const& x)
{
    // Could not calculate a real *OR* complex square root, so report error.
}
```

It’s basically the same (though there are some gotchas that I will go into later). So you don’t really gain much by the extra error types in `composite_expected`. (Note that in cases where you’re using the monadic interface, there will be no difference, so there’s no point comparing them.)

So, in summary, I don’t see the need for an extended `expected` to handle the case of multiple error types. In those very, very rare cases where you actually want multiple error types, it’s just as easy to put those error types in a variant or a custom struct… *and*, in doing so, you make the different error type cases more meaningful and ergonmic. Even `outcome`’s multiple error types seem a bit… much… for most use cases, but at least with `outcome`, there is a meaningful semantic to the two (and only two) error types.

## Code review

Since the OP’s concern is only with the `composite_expected` class, I will ignore all the other code, regardless of problems, and assume it all works… well, not as described, because nothing is *described*—there is literally not a single comment *anywhere* in the code—but I will assume it works as I *hope* it works, given the names. More likely than not, my assumptions will be wrong, but… what can one do? There are no comments explaining *anything*.

Comment your code! The more the better! Obviously don’t make stupid comments like the classic “`++i; // increments i`”, but any high-level points or logical implications should be explained.

Nothing in your code is obvious to anyone else. It may be obvious to *you* what `variant_add<variant<A, B>, variant<C, D>>` does… but everyone else is wondering whether this gives `variant<A, B, C, D>` or `variant<A, B, variant<C, D>>`. A single line comment would remove the confusion.

Anywho, I’ll start the review with just the definition of `composite_expected`.

```
    template <typename Other>
        requires details::is_variant_v<typename Other::variant_t>
    using united_t =
        typename details::variant_add<
            typename details::variant_add<
                std::variant_alternative_t<0, typename Other::variant_t>,
                details::variant_slice_first_t<variant_t>
            >::type,
            details::variant_slice_first_t<typename Other::variant_t>>::type;

    template <typename Ret, typename Other>
        requires details::is_variant_v<std::remove_cvref_t<Other>>
    static auto united( Other&& other )
    {
        return other.index() == 0
                ? from_variant_t<Ret>( details::make_variant_index_t<Ret>::fromOther( 0, 0, std::forward<Other>( other ) ) )
                : from_variant_t<Ret>(
                        details::make_variant_index_t<Ret>::fromOther( sizeof...( Errs ) + other.index(), other.index(), std::forward<Other>( other ) )
                );
    }
```

I literally have no idea what any of this is supposed to do. Like, not even the faintest notion. Nothing is explained. Not a single comment.

It’s not even possible to deduce what’s going on from the names. What does `united` mean?

The only way I could suss out what any of this does would be to dig into templates of templates of templates of templates… and… no. Just… no.

```
    template <typename J>
    struct from_variant;

    template <typename ...Ts>
    struct from_variant<std::variant<Ts...>>
    {
        using type = composite_expected<Ts...>;
    };

    template <typename ...Ts>
    using from_variant_t = typename from_variant<Ts...>::type;
```

Why is this part of the public interface?

```
    template <typename ...Args>
    static composite_expected<T, Errs...> fromErr( size_t errIndex, Args&& ...args )
    {
        return composite_expected( details::make_variant_index_t<decltype( variant_ )>::fromArgs( errIndex + 1, std::forward<Args>( args )... ) );
    }
```

My first problem with this function is that the index is a run-time argument, and not a compile-time, template argument.

See, if the index was a compile-time arguments, I could write:

```
composite_expected<T, const char*>::fromErr<0>("Could not take sqr-root of negative number");
```

… and that index would be *compile-time* checked. As in, if I wrote a `1` by accident, it wouldn’t even compile. With the current code, it looks like it will throw a `make_variant_index_error`… which is weird, for a couple of reasons. But we’ll get back to that.

Also, if the index were a compile-time template argument, all of the machinery you need to make runtime indices works goes away. No more need for `make_variant_index_t`, `make_variant_index_impl_from_other`, etc..

And if you think about it… in what use case, ever, would you ever need to construct an error-ed `composite_expected`, and *not* know, at compile-time, which error you’re constructing? That will never happen. So why go through all the gymnastics to make it possible?

But my main problem with this function is how un-ergonomic it is. This is literally the *only* way to construct an error-ed `composite_index`, and the example given shows how ugly it is to actually do:

```
template <typename T>
composite_expected<T, const char*> sqrt( T x )
{
    /* ... */
        return composite_expected<T, const char*>::fromErr( 0, /* args */ );
}
```

In order to create an error state, one has to repeat the entire type… like, *all* of it, with the expected value type, and all of the error types (here there is just one, but the whole point of `composite_expected` is that there can be several). If you imagine this function could return one of several error types, then it would look like this:

```
auto func(/* ... */) -> composite_expected<T, ErrT1, ErrT2, ErrT3>
{
    /* ... */

    else if (/* error type 1 */)
        return composite_expected<T, ErrT1, ErrT2, ErrT3>::fromErr(0, /* args */);
    else if (/* error type 2 */)
        return composite_expected<T, ErrT1, ErrT2, ErrT3>::fromErr(1, /* args */);
    else if (/* error type 3 */)
        return composite_expected<T, ErrT1, ErrT2, ErrT3>::fromErr(2, /* args */);
    
}
```

Now imagine we want to change `ErrT2` to `ErrT2b`.

Yeah, sure, you can “fix” this problem with type aliases, but… well, take a look at what `std::expected` looks like (obviously only with a single error type):

```
auto func(/* ... */) -> std::expected<T, ErrT>
{
    /* ... */

    else if (/* error */)
        return std::unexpected{/* args */};
        // or, if this is not a simple, implicit conversion:
        //  return std::unexpected<ErrT>{std::inplace_t, /* args */};
    
}
```

If we imagine extending that to multiple types:

```
auto func(/* ... */) -> hypothetical::expected<T, ErrT1, ErrT2, ErrT3>
{
    /* ... */

    else if (/* error type 1 */)
        return std::unexpected<ErrT1>{std::inplace_t, /* args */};
    else if (/* error type 2 */)
        return std::unexpected<ErrT2>{std::inplace_t, /* args */};
    else if (/* error type 3 */)
        return std::unexpected<ErrT3>{std::inplace_t, /* args */};
    
}
```

This, of course, assumes that the `ErrT`’s are completely distinct—you can’t implicitly construct an `ErrT2` from an `ErrT1`, for example. If they’re not, then you’d need to specify the index. So:

```
auto func(/* ... */) -> hypothetical::expected<T, ErrT1, ErrT2, ErrT3>
{
    /* ... */

    else if (/* error type 1 */)
        return hypothetical::unexpected<0, ErrT1>{std::inplace_t, /* args */};
    else if (/* error type 2 */)
        return hypothetical::unexpected<1, ErrT2>{std::inplace_t, /* args */};
    else if (/* error type 3 */)
        return hypothetical::unexpected<2, ErrT3>{std::inplace_t, /* args */};
    
}
```

And it *might* be possible (I’d need to sit down and think it through to be sure) to do:

```
auto func(/* ... */) -> hypothetical::expected<T, ErrT1, ErrT2, ErrT3>
{
    /* ... */

    else if (/* error type 1 */)
        return hypothetical::unexpected<0>{std::inplace_t, /* args */};
    else if (/* error type 2 */)
        return hypothetical::unexpected<1>{std::inplace_t, /* args */};
    else if (/* error type 3 */)
        return hypothetical::unexpected<2>{std::inplace_t, /* args */};
    
}
```

It would be nice if you were able to *either* specify just the type (in cases where the types are distinct) *or* the index *or* both (for safety). But even in the worst case, where you have to specify both the index and the type, that’s still better than the case of `fromErr()`, where you have to specify *all* the types—value and error—*and* the index.

Back to `make_variant_index_error`: it seems strange to throw a custom error for this because we already have a bunch of standard errors that would make more sense: `std::out_of_range` is probably the best choice. But even if you were going to make a custom error, it would make more sense to inherit from `logic_error` rather than `runtime_error`; after all, if someone gives a bad index, that’s on them; that’s a problem they could have avoided if they’d cared to.

```
    template <typename ...Args>
    static composite_expected<T, Errs...> fromVal( Args&& ...args )
    {
        return composite_expected( std::in_place_index<0>, std::forward<Args>( args )... );
    }
```

This function seems superfluous, from an API point of view. `auto v = composite_expected<T, E1 /*, E2,... */>(/* args */);` is shorter, and more intuitive than `auto v = composite_expected<T, E1 /*, E2,... */>::fromVal(/* args */);`.

The problem is, of course, they don’t do the same thing… but we’ll get to that next.

```
    template <typename ...Args>
    explicit composite_expected( Args&& ...args ):
        variant_( std::forward<Args>( args )... )
    {}

    template <typename TFwd>
        requires std::convertible_to<std::remove_cvref_t<TFwd>, T>
    composite_expected( TFwd&& val ):
        variant_( std::in_place_index<0>, std::forward<TFwd>( val ) )
    {}
```

There is something very weird going on here.

When I do `auto v = composite_expected<T, E1 /*, E2, ...*/>(U{/*args*/});`, then if `U` is *implicitly* convertible to `T`, the second constructor will be selected, and I’ll get a non-error value in `v`. Good. That’s what I expected. If I do `auto v = composite_expected<std::string, std::error_code>("foo");`, I get a non-error-ed `v` that holds a string. Great.

But if `U` is not *implicitly* convertible to `T`, the *second* constructor will be selected. And the weirdness here comes from the fact that that constructor does not use `in_place_index` to construct the value type… but instead uses `variant`’s converting constructor.

The reason why that’s weird is that the converting constructor won’t necessarily choose the first alternative if another alternative is a better match. Which means the argument given may be silently shunted to an error type.

For example, suppose you have a `composite_expected<string, string_view>`, and you do `auto s = ""s; auto v = composite_expected<string, string_view>{s};`. That will do the obvious, and you end up with v in the non-error-ed state, holding an empty string. All good. But then, at some later point, that first line becomes `auto s = ""sv;`. Such a minor change, and one that seems highly plausible—no need to construct a string here, right? It’s a compile-time string literal; we can use a string view. *But*… now `v` constructs in the error state, holding an empty string view. No warnings. No indications whatsoever of why `v`… which may be far away from `s`… is suddenly not what it was before.

I’m guessing the reason you did things this way is because you wanted the following to compile only when `U` is implicitly convertible to `T`:

```
auto f() -> composite_expected<T, E>
{
    return U{};
}
```

Okay, fine, but… this is not the way to go about this. We have conditional `explicit` these days, so you could write those two constructors as:

```
template <typename U>
explicit(std::convertible_to<U, T>) composite_expected(U&& u)
    : variant_{std::in_place_index<0>, std::forward<U>(u)}
{}
```

And the function above won’t compile if `U` is not *implicitly* convertible to `T`, but it *will* compile if `U` is *explicitly* convertible to `T`. And none of the error types will ever be considered (even if they’re a better match).

(If you want to also allow construction from *multiple* arguments, you would need another, non-conversion constructor to handle that. Or, you could use what you have now, but with `std::in_place_index<0>` in the unconstrained case as well.)

```
    [[nodiscard]] const variant_t& variant() const
    {
        return variant_;
    }

    variant_t&& variant()
    {
        return std::move( variant_ );
    }
```

These functions make no sense in the public interface, and expose the inner workings of the class. What if you decide to re-implement it in terms of `boost::variant` instead of `std::variant`? Or manually with a discriminated union?

```
    explicit operator bool() const
    {
        return variant_.index() == 0;
    }
```

This function is fine, but I wanted to point out that there’s a general lack of decoration that applies all throughout. For example, this function could be `noexcept` and `constexpr`.

```
    [[nodiscard]] const T& value() const
    {
        return std::get<0>( variant_ );
    }

    T&& value()
    {
        return std::get<0>( std::move( variant_ ) );
    }
```

There are some serious problems here.

The first function is (mostly) fine… although, I don’t really see the point of the `[[nodiscard]]`. You’re just returning a reference. There’s no cost if the user disregards it. There’s no point in calling the function if you’re just going to disregard the return, sure… but it’t not going to be a problem. I suppose this is a style thing, so if you really feel strongly about `[[nodiscard]]`, then fine, go ahead… but in that case, you really should be using it everywhere.

The real problem is the second function. Suppose I do this:

```
auto v = composite_expected<T, ...>{...};

auto v1 = v.value();    // this is fine (assuming v has a value)
auto v2 = v.value();    // boom
```

What happens on that boom line? Could be anything. Depends on `T`. The value in `v` was moved from in the first call to `value()`, and the only things you should safely expect to do with a moved-from object is either reassign it, or destroy it. *Using* it is a no-no.

And note that the value gets moved from any time you call it with a non-const object. The previous code is dangerous, but the following code is fine:

```
auto const v = composite_expected<T, ...>{...};

auto v1 = v.value();    // this is fine (assuming v has a value)
auto v2 = v.value();    // fine
```

Note that there is no indication in that first code block that the value has been moved from.

Moving a value silently out from under a user is a terrible idea. If something is going to be moved, it should be explicit. Or, at least, it should happen implicitly only in situations where anything other than a move would make no sense.

If you want the same “smart-moving” behaviour that `std::optional` or `std::expected` have, then in C++20, you have to write *four* functions, and use reference qualifiers:

```
auto value() &       -> T&        { return std::get<0>(variant_); }
auto value() const&  -> T const&  { return std::get<0>(variant_); }
auto value() &&      -> T&&       { return std::get<0>(std::move(variant_)); }
auto value() const&& -> T const&& { return std::get<0>(std::move(variant_)); }
```

And, technically, this doesn’t take `volatile` into account (but nobody does anyway).

As of C++23, you can use deducing `this` to simplify this to a single function.

But the bottom line is that silently moving the internal value in a member function that isn’t r-value reference qualified is asking for disaster.

```
    [[nodiscard]] std::variant<Errs...> error() const
    {
        return details::make_variant_index_t<std::variant<Errs...>>::fromOther( variant_.index() - 1, variant_.index(), variant_ );
    }

    std::variant<Errs...> error()
    {
        return details::make_variant_index_t<std::variant<Errs...>>::fromOther( variant_.index() - 1, variant_.index(), std::move( variant_ ) );
    }
```

Do these functions really make sense? Will there ever be a need to get the whole tuple of potential errors? (Assuming that’s what’s really going on here. Again, I don’t want to dig into the morass of `make_variant_index_t`.)

You’d like a function that just returns the error, sure, but that seems impossible, because which error is active (if any) can’t be known at compile time. The only alternative, then, seems to be to return a variant of all possibilities. So, pragmatically, this would seem to be the only option.

I would say this is a point where you should step back and think about practical usage of the design. The only things anyone is probably ever going to want to do with the error (if any) are:

1. ask which of the error types is active; and
2. use the active error value to do something (most likely report).

You already have a function that does 1: `errorIndex()`. (Though, I would add some form of `holds_alternative()`, so you can query by type.) So all you need is 2.

So how does `std::variant` handle the case of wanting to the use the active value to do something? It uses the visitor pattern.

So what if instead of querying for *all* potential errors, then having to dig through that to figure out which error is active, then doing what they want with the one true error, you let users skip the first two steps by also using the visitor pattern. Something like:

```
    template <typename F>
    auto visit_error(F&& f) -> decltype(auto)
    {
        return std::visit(std::forward<F>(f), _variant);
    }
```

(You’d need to quadruplicate the above to handle `const` and l-value/r-value references, or use deducing `this`.)

Usage:

```
composite_expected<T, E1, E2, E3> v = /* initialize to some error */;

struct error_handler_t
{
    auto operator()(E1 const&) { /* ... */ }
    auto operator()(E2 const&) { /* ... */ }
    auto operator()(E3 const&) { /* ... */ }
};

if (v)
    // use v
else
    v.visit_error(error_handler_t{});

// Or:
template <typename... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };

if (v)
    // use v
else
    v.visit_error(overloaded{
        [](E1 const&) { /* ... */ },
        [](E2 const&) { /* ... */ },
        [](E3 const&) { /* ... */ },
    });
```

This idea maps very nicely to a monadic interface:

```
auto wanted_value = v
    .and_then(do_something)
    .or_else(overloaded{
        [](E1 const&) { /* ... */ },
        [](E2 const&) { /* ... */ },
        [](E3 const&) { /* ... */ },
    });
```

For an actual, practical case:

```
auto wrap(T&& value) -> composite_expected<T>;  // no errors, no error types

auto square_root(T&&) ->
    composite_expected<T,
        std::invalid_argument   // if the arg is NaN (or some other invalid)
        std::domain_error       // if the arg is negative
    >;

auto to_string(T&&) ->
    composite_expected<std::string,
        std::bad_alloc  // if we ran out of memory
    >;

std::string result = my_wrap(input)
    .and_then(square_root)
    .and_then(to_string)
    .or_else(overloaded{
        // Note how the possible errors are all combined.
        [](std::invalid_argument const&) { return "not a number"s; },
        [](std::domain_error const&) { return "negative number"s; },
        [](std::domain_error const&) { return "ran out of memory"s; },
    });

// So:
//  input == 144; result == "12";
//  input == -1; result == "negative number";
//  input == <anything valid, but no mem left>; result == "out of memory";
```

`errorIndex()` is fine. (Though it could use `constexpr`, and some better documentation: like, what happens if there is no error? Is the return value supposed to be `std::variant_npos`? Or is that just not specified?)

```
    template <typename ...Args1, typename Functor, typename ...Args2>
        requires details::is_variant_v<typename std::invoke_result_t<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>::variant_t>
    auto then( Args1&& ...args1, Functor f, Args2&& ...args2 )
    {
        using Ret = united_t<std::invoke_result_t<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>>;
        return *this ? united<Ret>( std::invoke( f, std::forward<Args1>( args1 )..., std::move( value() ), std::forward<Args2>( args2 )... ).variant() )
                     : from_variant_t<Ret>( details::make_variant_index_t<Ret>::fromOther( variant_.index(), variant_.index(), std::move( variant_ ) ) );
    }

    template <typename ...Args1, typename Functor, typename ...Args2>
        requires details::is_variant_v<typename std::invoke_result_t<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>::variant_t>
    auto then( Args1&& ...args1, Functor f, Args2&& ...args2 ) const
    {
        using Ret = united_t<std::invoke_result_t<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>>;
        return *this ? united<Ret>( std::invoke( f, std::forward<Args1>( args1 )..., value(), std::forward<Args2>( args2 )... ).variant() )
                     : from_variant_t<Ret>( details::make_variant_index_t<Ret>::fromOther( variant_.index(), variant_.index(), variant_ ) );
    }

    template <typename ...Args1, typename Functor, typename ...Args2>
        requires ( std::invocable<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>
            && !requires { typename std::invoke_result_t<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>::variant_t; } )
    auto then( Args1&& ...args1, Functor f, Args2&& ...args2 )
    {
        using Ret = std::variant<std::invoke_result_t<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>, Errs...>;
        return *this ? from_variant_t<Ret>::fromVal( std::invoke( f, std::forward<Args1>( args1 )..., std::move( value() ), std::forward<Args1>( args2 )... ) )
                     : from_variant_t<Ret>( details::make_variant_index_t<Ret>::fromOther( variant_.index(), variant_.index(), std::move( variant_ ) ) );
    }

    template <typename ...Args1, typename Functor, typename ...Args2>
        requires ( std::invocable<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>
            && !requires { typename std::invoke_result_t<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>::variant_t; } )
   auto then( Args1&& ...args1, Functor f, Args2&& ...args2 ) const
    {
        using Ret = std::variant<std::invoke_result_t<Functor, Args1..., T, Args2...>, Errs...>;
        return *this ? from_variant_t<Ret>::fromVal( std::invoke( f, std::forward<Args1>( args1 )..., value(), std::forward<Args2>( args2 )... ) )
                     : from_variant_t<Ret>( details::make_variant_index_t<Ret>::fromOther( variant_.index(), variant_.index(), variant_ ) );
    }
```

Okay, figuring out what’s going on here with no comments is going to be slog, so I’ll have to make some assumptions. It looks like you have 4 variations, but with `const`, non-`const` we can boil that down to 2. It looks like the first 2 deal with functions that return wrapped objects, while the latter two deal with functions that deal with unwrapped objects. So, basically, the first two are “bind”, and the last two are “map” (this may or may not match “standard” monadic terminology; I’ve never cared enough to really research this, because I just use the C++ terms “then” and “transform”).

Okay, so if you are trying to do both bind and map with the same name, you already have a problem. There’s a reason those two operations have different names in pretty much every implementation of monads. When the function object returns a wrapped object, sometimes you want it wrapped again, and sometimes not.

In C++, the first two functions are generally named “`and_then`”, and the second two “`transform`”.

By disambiguating them with different names, you avoid a whole host of usability headaches, *and* simplify the understanding of what’s going on. Now it’s no longer a mystery when a function returns `composite_expected<T, Errs...>`, whether the actual application in `then()` will return `composite_expected<T, Errs...>` or `composite_expected<composite_expected<T, Errs...>, Errs...>` or who knows what else.

Okay, so now that I have sussed out what’s really going on here (I would have been spared a lot of this work with some comments!!!), I can guess that maybe `united_t` is somehow collecting together the error types in `Errs`, and the error types returned by the function. How exactly is still a mystery. Are duplicate types coalesced? Are the types from the function placed before or after the types from the class?

Anyway, I assume they’re all collected somehow, in some order.

Now, the same bug that exists in `value()` exists here: you are very silently moving the object’s value out from under the user, with no warning, and the only way the user can possibly know is if they take the time to sit down and parse apart this very long and very complicated function definition and spot the hidden `std::move`… and realize what it means.

As with `value()`, the way this *should* be fixed is by quadruplicating the function (or, in C++23, using deducing `this`). [This is how it’s actually done in `std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/and_then).

I would also suggest that you should be taking the function by forwarding-reference, rather than by-value. It may be non-copyable, or expensive to copy, and you don’t need to copy in any case.

But the main issue I have with these functions is that they’re wildly over-complicated, for no real benefits. You want to be able to work with functions that take multiple arguments, where the key argument is in any position. Fine. But we already have tools for that.

Consider this:

```
auto result = f(input)
    .then(a, b, c, d, e);
```

Now, tell me which of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` is the function.

Compare that to this:

```
auto result = f(input)
    .then(std::bind(b, a, _1, c, d, e));
```

Now it’s clear: `b` is the function.

`std::bind` is not only clearer, it’s more powerful. What if you want to use the value twice in the argument list? You can’t do it with your way, but with `std::bind` it’s easy:

```
auto result = f(input)
    // basically calls g(f(input), f(input)) (but without calling f twice)
    .then(std::bind(g, _1, _1));
```

So I would say don’t bother with all the complexity of supporting before/after arguments. It makes your code more complex, and user code harder to read. And there’s a superior, standard solution.

```
    template <std::invocable<T> Functor>
    auto operator >>( Functor f )
    {
        return then( f );
    }

    template <std::invocable<T> Functor>
    auto operator >>( Functor f ) const
    {
        return then( f );
    }
```

I am *really* not a fan of appropriating operators for non-standard behaviours. I get that it sucks that C++ doesn’t have Haskell’s `>>=`… but you shouldn’t try to shoehorn it in.

It’s especially problematic when it creates ambiguity. For example, consider this line from your test code: `auto z = x >> sqrt<int>;` Without looking up the type of `x`, this could be a shift operation, or a stream read. (Yes, using `<<` and `>>` for streaming was also a bad idea, one that has been expensive and miserable, and recent standards have starting moving away from that to function calls (cf `std::format()`).) Now it can also be a function chain. Not great.

And it doesn’t seem to add much:

```
auto z = x >> sqrt<int>;

auto z = x
    .and_then(sqrt<int>);
```

The latter seems much more readable to me. It gets even more so as the chains get more complicated, and you starting adding `transform`s and `or_else`s and other stuff. For example:

```
auto z = (x >> sqrt<int>).value_or(0);

auto z = x
    .and_then(sqrt<int>)
    .value_or(0);
```

Also, keep in mind that there may be actual monadic chaining operators in the future. Proposals in flight include [`|>`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2011r1.html) and [`??`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2561r0.html). (The `|>` paper actually [illustrates the hazard of what you’re doing](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2011r1.html#what-to-do-about-ranges-going-forward). The ranges library co-opted `|` for pipelining. Because of that, if we ever get `|>`, the ranges library will have to truck around unnecessary and expensive support for `|` for many years to come… possibly forever.)

I’d toss these operators, split `then()` into `and_then()` and `transform()` (and remove support for prefix and postfix args), and that way your type will play well with other monadic types in the standard, past, present, and future.